Need to get concrete subfloor with raised crack within flooring tolerance
I've researched this issue quite a lot already but would appreciate some input because I'm not sure which approach is best.
I'm laying engineered hardwood over a concrete subfloor in an approx 11x12 room that is part of a finished basement. It will be an art studio. The tolerance of the flooring is 1/4" over 6'. After removing the carpet, I discovered a large crack down the center of the room that has resulted in the center of the room being raised. Imagine snapping a square cracker in half with the break upwards, if that makes sense. It's worse at one end of the room than another. In the first photo you can see how the floor raises up each side of the crack - that wall is about 4 ft and the difference at each end from the center is 1/4-1/2". There is also some unevenness along the length of the crack (2nd photo) but it's not as bad as the side-to-side (1st photo).




I'm really just aiming to get this to 'adequate' rather than perfect, since it will be a workspace and we don't plan on being in the house for years and years, meaning I just need to get within the 1/4" tolerance. I know it will cost a bit but I'm trying to not spend hundreds. I know I should do it 100% right but for now it just needs to get the job done of making this room useable.
The obvious solution seems self leveling compound BUT because the problem is a raised area down the center of the room running lengthways, rather than some low spots, I would suspect it would take a lot of compound. Other possible solutions are to add a plywood subfloor and shims, or since the raised area does seem to be centered around the crack, I considered breaking up the concrete around the crack and then refilling with whatever would be appropriate. I could also grind it but would prefer a cleaner solution.
Your advice is very much appreciated!

A raised crack in a slab might mean more problems(flooding) if you finish the room.  How long have you been there?  Slabs might crack, but being raise is usually do to bad pouring, water pressure under the slab, or earth movement.

The house was built in 1975 and we've been here for 6 years and there has been carpet down all that time (installed before we moved in). I did notice water marks on the carpet and rusted nails, but it was below the window, so I think that is what caused it. I haven't noticed anything with the carpet in terms of molding or any indication of water, just those old water stains when I lifted it. I have a photo but I don't think I can add it to the comments.

Leveling compound is the best solution.  Any other method is a bandage that you will regret later down the road.

Leveling compound, or simply grinding the high part to get you enough slope.  Most flooring types have a slope tolerance, e.g. 1/8" over 6'.
